# Python + Apache + wsgi - How to turn on the cgitb debug on browser?

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi, cgitb

How can I turn on the cgitb debug on browser in wsgi?

```
# enable debugging
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()

def application(environ, start_response):

# build the response body possibly using the environ dictionary
response_body = 'The request method was %s' % environ['REQUEST_METHOD']

status = '200 OK'

response_headerx = [('Content-Type', 'text/plain'),
                   ('Content-Length', str(len(response_body)))]

# Send them to the server using the supplied function
start_response(status, response_headers)

return [response_body]
```

error only can be found in Apache log's error.log,

> NameError: global name 'response_headers' is not defined, referer:
>   http://127.0.0.1/python-

while on the browser, I get this,

> Server error!
>
> The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete
>   your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in
>   a CGI script.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>
> Error 500
>
> 127.0.0.1 Apache/2.4.7 (Win32) mod_wsgi/4.4.12 Python/2.7.10 PHP/5.6.4

Any ideas?

Comment: The cgitb module is for use with CGI scripts, not WSGI applications. Instead see https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/DebuggingTechniques#Error_Catching_Middleware but don't use such things on production servers.

Comment: Thanks. But I get this error - `ImportError: No module named paste.exceptions.errormiddleware, `

Comment: `pip install paste` is what it takes

Comment: I see typo in code. You created variable 'response_headerx', rename it to response_headers